# What are the limits to J'onn Jonzz shape-shifting ability?

Tags: dc, martian-manhunter

In various media and comics, the Martian Manhunter is shown to have the ability to change his molecular structure. This includes making it so loose he becomes intangible, to becoming so dense he's harder than any known Earth metal, to altering his appearance, length, size and even fluidity.

It's always been somewhat inconsistent, though.

In some versions, he can just take on the appearance and traits of other, similarly sized beings; in others, he can rival Plastic Man in his malleability; in others still, he can actually alter his form to match other elements, like rock or metal. In some cases, he can do this only for a limited time or with constant concentration; in others, he can maintain a given form indefinitely, or at least until he's put under extreme weakness or pain.

Granted, a lot of this would be determined by

1. the particular time period of the comics or media, due to power creep, and
2. the writer dealing with him at the time.

Still, I was wondering if there were any panels or videos with J'onn *himself* showing or speaking of the limits, or elaborating on how his power works?

Also any showing his powers in action would also be useful.